# Multiple downloads support in one time purchase per customer code - Easy Digital Downloads

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Im trying to create a function to limit the purchase for customers. I want to disable purchase form if a customer has already purchased the product.

Its working fine if I use only one post ID but I cannot add multiple downloads in the function.

the working code with only one ID.

```
// Limit purchase per user.
add_filter( 'edd_can_checkout', 'sd_limit_purchase' );
function sd_limit_purchase(){
    $user_id        = get_current_user_id(); // Get the current customer's ID
    $downloads  = edd_get_users_purchased_products( $user_id );// Get all of the products the customer has purchased in the past
    $can_checkout   = true; // Allow checkout for now
    $in_cart        = edd_item_in_cart( '50576' ); // Check to see if our download is in the customer's cart. Change 57 to your download's ID.

    if ( $in_cart == true ){ // If the item isn't in the customer's cart we don't need to go any further.
        if ( ! empty( $downloads ) ){ // If the customer hasn't purchased anything before we don't need to go any further.
            foreach ( $downloads as $download ){ // Loop through each product the customer has purchased before.
                switch ( $download->ID ) {
                    case $in_cart: // If the customer has purchased the product we want to limit one per customer set an error message. Again change 57 to your product's ID.
                    edd_set_error( 'already_purchased', apply_filters( 'edd_pc_error_message', __( 'You have already downloaded this plugin. There is a limit of one per customer for the free products. A free product license is lifetime and there are no site limits, please go to your account to redownload it!' ) ) );
                        $can_checkout = false;
                        break;

                    default:
                        $can_checkout = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            edd_print_errors(); // Display the errors on the checkout page.
        }
    }
    return $can_checkout;
}
```

How can I give multiple downloads support using array? I cannot figure it out when I use multiple post IDs with commas its work only for the first product.

So I have tried using `$in_cart = edd_item_in_cart( '50576', '50577', '50578' );` but no luck there.

Do you have any idea or different method for this?

Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Can you please show us the `edd_item_in_cart()` function as well? An array is not simply a separation of strings with commas, but looks like this: `array('50576', '50577', '50578')`

Comment: Try `edd_items_in_cart('50576,50577,50578')`. If you're using [EDD Additional Shortcodes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/edd-additional-shortcodes/) it is listed here as accepting a comma separated string.

Comment: I have tried all @wigi but its working only for the first ID in the array Wild Beard Im going to try your code right now.

Comment: edd_items_in_cart doesn't work

Comment: @AlbanoAlbanese I've had a look at the code of EDD. It seems that it is not possible to use it for multiple entries at once. You probably need to call  `edd_item_in_cart()` multiple times. The `edd_item_in_cart()` has the following parameter structure: `function edd_item_in_cart( $download_id = 0, $options = array() ) {}`

Comment: I have created multiple variables for each post id and a new case for each variable that was the solution thanks for your help.